# Downloading Documents from lotus notes

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I am using the NCSO.jar api for lotus notes. Now I can create the connection remotely to the domino server. I tried to download the documents created by the lotus notes such as the .odt documents. But it is not success. my code:

```
     database = session.getDatabase(host, "names.nsf", false);
     DocumentCollection documentCollection = database.getAllDocuments();
```

The returned result is always same and not included any .odt files. So is there another way to download the documents created by ibm notes?
for example, I use lotus notes created a documents like a test.odt which is saved under the myDocuments folder. I want use an external application to download this file.

Comment: As we figured out in a chat this question is about how can I access IBM Lotus Symphony documents created in Notes client.

Comment: Is it "How can I.." or "How can other people..."?  If it is "How can I...", then since the documents are stored in My Documents there's no need for an external application to go through Notes in order to get the documents.

Comment: The lotus notes is running on a server, I tried to write an external java program to access those documents created. Maybe, how can other people ... is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely the database.getAllDocuments() will return all Notes documents in the specified database - in this case names.nsf.  This doesn't include external files created via Lotus Notes - so, I'd look at two options:

[1]  Store the path of the file created in the Notes document and use this information from the field information in the  NotesDocumentCollection returned, or

[2]  Attach the file created to the Notes document in a RTF (Rich Text Field) - the attachment will then be returned in the NotesDocumentCollection and you can retrieve it/manipulate it by processing the RTF which contains it.

But remember, if you store only references to the file (name and path etc as in [1] above) then you'll have to store these on a network share - not your 'local' machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you mean, we should extend the lotus notes itself to store the path of the created file?

Comment: Hi Alvin, hope you're well.  If users create documents and store locally then other users will be unable to see them - only the person creating the .dot document.  So, what I'm suggesting is to store the .dot documents on a network share that all users can see.  If you want to process these documents via Lotus Notes then Notes somehow needs to know about the existence of these documents - either by storing the path and filename in a Notes Document or by embedding (attaching) the actual .dot file in the Notes Document (via an RTF) field.  It may help if you expand on your requirements.

Comment: You could also create a NotesAgent to retrieve files from a network share, build a list and write this to a single NotesDocument.  But if you wish to drive this process via Notes then you may wish to create the said .dot documents via Notes (lots of examples on web) and give the files unique names that you store in a Notes Document relating to this file (the files still reside on the network share but we have a Notes document identifying the path/filename.  Your users can then access this file via Notes but make sure they don't change the filename (save as)!